What is Microsoft Edge Stable?
There are two UWP applications named Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge and Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Stable in Windows 11. I wonder differences and correlation between two.

"Stable" usually denotes the current public release; other versions might be alpha or beta or nightly tests.
